# Accesing images present in project inside extensions

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, file-access

I have created a `NotificationContentExtension` for my app. I need a image in it to show in my custom expanded notitifcation.The image is present in root of project.

```
/myProj
  /myImage.png
  /myProj
  /myProjTests
  /Content
/Pods
```

My project structure is like above and I am accessing image like

```
Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myImage", withExtension: "png")
```

When I push notification the expanded notification ui is not shown. But when I remove this piece of code then my wire frame of expanded notification ui is shown.

Is this not the way of accessing any file in app extensions?

Answer (score 1):

If your project is split into multiple bundles (frameworks, cocoapods, etc) you may need to refer to the proper bundle in which the image is contained and not assume it is always the main.

To get the bundle associated with your current class:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
```

You can substitute `self` for whatever class it is you are trying to locate.

Comment: I tried replacing self with class name present in app, but I am not shown in intellisense of xcode.

Comment: I tried accessing bundle using bundle identifier but I am not getting anything in return

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial, see if it helps: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/loading-resources-from-a-framework/